# On the meaning of "as of present"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests, discourse-markers

I have a little semantic challenge - I would like to state that something has been and still is happening (up to the present moment) in a certain way, but may soon end / change. In principle, this is not an obstacle in an out-of-context situation, however, my problem is that I am making a translation (from a synthetic language into English) and have to "stick" to the original sentence structure, which is:

> This is A, functioning *as of present* by means of B. Due to sth, A will soon be renovated...

My question is whether the adverb "*as of present*" incorporates the meaning that I would like to achieve - both of nowness and of expected recent change. In the original language this sense is achieved through an adverb in the instrumental case and for this reason "presently", "currently", "now", etc. are not appropriate translations (since they carry locative meaning).

PS My main concern is that "*as of present*" may be misinterpreted as "from the present moment onward", similarly to "*as of now*" / "*as of this moment*" - quite the opposite of what I wish to imply.

Comment: Can't it be **till now, till the present time/moment**?

Comment: It's *as **at** present* - the way things are now (and probably have been for quite some time in the past). *As **of** now* means *starting from now* (i.e. - whatever is being referred to didn't exist or wasn't true before now).

Comment: I'd say "functioning at the present time"

Comment: @FumbleFingers "As of" does mean also "so far" - As of now, three bodies have been found. And according to Longman dictionary, it can also mean "on a particular date or time" ("as at" in BrE).

Comment: @JohnV: I don't think it's reasonable to say ***as of*** means ***so far***. If it's followed by ***now*** (or any other explicitly specified "point" in time) it means ***from** [some specified time] **onwards*** (by implication, ***not previously***, whereas ***so far*** implies ***previously AND now***). And don't forget ***as** [of] **yet***, which I'd say is a "negative polarity" item, in that it nearly always occurs in *negating* contexts *(something has **not*** happened as [of] yet).*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I believe the meaning is actually determined mostly by the tenses used. What about "As of now, we have not found any evidence" - how does this mean from [now] on? Even the dictionary state "as of" can mean "until".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please take a look here: http://learnersdictionary.com/qa/as-of-today  They explicitly mention "this meaning is close to the meaning of the expression so far" in a sentence "As of today, only three survivors have been found."

Comment: @JohnV: Perhaps it's a matter of opinion. Personally, I don't like ***as of now = so far*** much, and a Google Books search for [*As of now, we have not*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22As+of+now,+we+have+not%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNQB_xCNx9FKnBZ5NvJAYCnQN6DLlQ:1570463194397&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy0tamv4rlAhXsURUIHW10BjoQpwUIIQ&biw=1475&bih=906&dpr=1) finds just **2** instances (one of which is clearly "below par" Nigerian English). That's got to be balanced against what looks like ***hundreds*** of written instances of ***So far** we have not*.

Comment: (ditto for [***As yet** we have not*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22As+yet+we+have+not%22))

Comment: @FumbleFingers So the examples such as "As of now, we have found only two bodies" are incorrect or ambiguous? I am just trying to understand. Would it not be the same as saying We have found two bodies so far"?

Comment: The ***as of now / so far*** distinction is a *very* fine point, more to do with "good style" than "correct phrasing". I wouldn't make too much of it. The important thing you should be learning from responses to your question is that ***as of present*** is completely non-idiomatic. If you want to be pointlessly verbose you can say *as of **the** present **moment / time / day / ...***, but it would be easier to just stick with ***as of now*** (or in your exact cited context, ***currently***, since that's what you ***really*** mean).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not the OP here, just found the question :) If I may add one thing - In the other question you stated "as of now - from now on" but what about the maning "at this moment"? Cambridge: at a particular date or time. ?**This issue may need attention later but, as of now, we are happy with the decision that we have taken.** In the examples I can see that when the present simple is used, the meaning is likely this.

Comment: @JohnV: Sorry for my earlier lack of attention. My position is that I think that Cambridge "so far" definition (with example *As of today, only three survivors have been found*) is a bit "sloppy, misleading". I'd tend to think of *that* usage as more akin to *the latest information we have [today] is that...* It's actually more common with a "time specifier" somewhen in the ***recent past*** rather than ***today***...

Comment: ...for example, *As of 10 o'clock this morning, the stock market was up 25 points* - where ***As of*** effectively adds a slight *emphasis* (over the "default" ***At** 10 o'clock*) to the fact that an actual time has been specified (which implies the situation is "fluid", so later information is likely to change). But to some extent this sense conflicts with the "so far" definition, particularly when the time-specifier is something like ***today, now, the present moment***. So I'd avoid it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. And what about the meaning "at this moment", that also comes from Cambridge: This issue may need attention later but, as of now, we are happy with the decision that we have taken.  //So there are truly like 3 different meanings :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[As of/from](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-of-from)*** means: 
​

> ***starting from a particular time or date***:
>   - As of next month, all the airline's fares will be going up.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

"As of present" will convey the same idea as "as of now" so it will not suit your purpose.

You may use the different tense:

- This is A, ***which has been functioning*** by means of B. Due to sth, A will soon be removed.

Actually usage may be tricky as suggested in the following post from M-W about the meaning of ***[as of today](http://learnersdictionary.com/qa/as-of-today)***:

> The different meanings of as of today:
>
> ***1)*** As of today can mean “***from the beginning up until now, including today,”*** as in this example:
>   -  As of today, only three survivors have been found.
>
> ***This meaning is close to the meaning of the expression so far***.
>
> ***2)*** On the other hand, it can also mean “***starting today and going forward into the future,***” as in this example:
>   - As of today, all passengers must check their luggage before boarding the plane.
>
> ***This meaning is close to the meaning of the expression going forward***.
>
> ***3)*** As of today even has a third meaning, which is less common than the other two. It can mean “today, only” with the implication that things are likely to change.

How to tell:

> If you’re wondering how to tell which meaning applies in a particular case, the best way to tell is by looking for context clues, especially in the verb tenses. In the examples below, the clues are described in parentheses.
>
> - As of today, Ron Paul has won 18 delegates nationally, compared with 105 for former Massachusetts Gov. Mitt Romney. (The present perfect verb – has won – tells you that this started in the past. As of today = so far.)
> - We as of today have not found out what happened to Jennifer. 
>     (The present perfect verb – have not found out –tells you that this started in the past. As of today = so far.)
> - As of today, no late homework is going to be accepted. 
>     (The future verb – is going to – tells you this is about the future. As of today = going forward.)
> - As of today, the members of the European Union are as follows: 1) Germany, 2) Austria, 3) United Kingdom, 4) Belgium, 5) Bulgaria, 6) The Czech Republic, 7) Denmark, 8) Estonia, 9) Finland, 10) France, …. 
>     (The present tense verb – is – tells you that this is about today, only.)
>
> ***As you can see from these examples, the verb tense is usually a good clue. But when in doubt, think about what’s most logical.***

Comment: What does "*here is where we are as of present*" mean then? I'm confused.